# How do I sort and rank the data set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set and I need to sort and rank something like this:

```
                d0   d1   d2   d3 
configuration                          
theta0         1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  
theta1         3.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  
theta2         2.0  3.0  4.0  2.0  
theta3         4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0
```

While my data set is something like this:

```
configuration  d0  d1  d2  d3
theta0       0.89 0.82 0.87 0.86
theta1       0.73,0.84,0.85,0.78
theta2       0.81,0.79,0.71,0.85
theta3       0.64,0.65,0.99,0.61
```

Where individual column is sorted and given a rank,

```
for dataset_name, dataset_values in copy_data.items():
    sorted_list = dataset_values.sort_values(ascending=False)
    count = 1
    print(">>")
    print(sorted_list)
    for item in sorted_list:
        copy_data[dataset_name][copy_data[dataset_name] == item] = count
        count += 1
```

is there a better way to optimize it?

Comment: Basically the definition of [`DataFrame.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html): `df.rank(ascending=False)`

Comment: how do I implement instead of for loop? @ALollz

Comment: also, it should be sequential, which means when two values have the same value it should have a consecutive ranking. @ALollz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
df.rank(ascending=False, method='first')
```

this will rank with highest first and rank entries as they are ordered in the column if there are multiple occurances of the same value

Comment: also, it should be sequential, which means when two values have the same value it should have a consecutive ranking